# Sending data through socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio, file-transfer

I am doing an android app in which i have to setup a functionality like ShareIt of Sending and receiving files from one device to other.
I am able to do it but i have to call the receive method again and again manually from receiving end.
I want to ask how to judge or initiate the receive method of socket automatically when the sender clicks on the sending button after selecting the files.

```
  buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("asdfd", IP_ADDRESS);
             clientRxThread =
                    new ClientRxThread(
                            IP_ADDRESS,
                            SocketServerPORT);

            clientRxThread.start();
        }});
}
```

On button click at receiving end i am making the socket connection with the sender IPAddress and the port number  through this thread.

```
 private class ClientRxThread extends Thread {
    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;

    ClientRxThread(String address, int port) {
        dstAddress = address;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                receive(socket);
                RecieveActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(RecieveActivity.this,
                                "Finished",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                final String eMsg = "Something wrong: " + e.getMessage();
                RecieveActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(RecieveActivity.this,
                                eMsg,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This is my thread to make the connection and call the receive method from this thread.

```
public void receive(Socket sockett){
    try {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sockett.getInputStream()));
        int number = dis.readInt();
        File[] files = new File[number];
        System.out.println("Number of Files to be received: " +number);
        for(int i = 0; i< number;i++) {

            long fileLength = dis.readLong();
            String fileName = dis.readUTF();
            final int progressInt = 100/number * (i+1);

            files[i] = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/HotspotDemo",
                    fileName);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files[i]);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) bos.write(dis.read());

            bos.close();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressInt);
                }
            });
        }
        dis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

and Here is the receive method where i save the files which are being sent from sender end.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: So you send files. And you receive files. Why?

Comment: `Thanks In Advance.`

Comment: `On button click at receiving end i am calling to accept the socket connection `. No. That is code for a client who tries to establish a connection with a server. Clients do not accept connections.

Comment: If the sender is a server then it can only send to connected clients. A server cannot start a client of course.  Rethink.

Comment: @greenapps yes, you are right. I am accepting the connection at the sender end only,  but my question is that how can i receive files without clicking on that receive button again and again, i mean how to call that receive method whenever the sender accepts the connection and sends files without clicking the button again and again?? BTW thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do not close the connection. Keep a permanent connection.

Comment: `whenever the sender accepts the connection `. Please do not talk in such way. It's the server who listens and accepts clients. Sending can be done by both.

Comment: @greenapps ok, i'll keep a permanent connection, but i am still not able to get how to call that receive() method whenever the sender sends some files.

Comment: Having a permanent connection means that the receiving side is always trying to receive. What is the problem?   The receiving side will always try to read().

Comment: @greenapps But do i need to implement any listener or something? to start that method, to call that socket.getInputStream ?

Comment: The client only listens for messages when it read()s from the input stream. So the client should always read(). So as soon as the client connects you determine the input stream and make a loop where you read().